# AWS account A->B->C S3 bucket policy access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS Account B i have S3 bucket with the following bucket policy:

- allow to put from Account A (working fine)
- allow to list from Account C (working fine)
- allow to get object from Account C (not working fine)

The policy is the following:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "ACCOUNT_A"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "MYBUCKET/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "ACCOUNT_A"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "MYBUCKET"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "ACCOUNT_C"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "MYBUCKET/*",
                "MYBUCKET"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Why from AWS Account C i can List but not GetObject ? (i do suspect it's because of the ownership: it's Account A who is the owner, but how to fix it)

Thanks,

Comment: Are you having difficulties with specific objects? Were these objects uploaded by a different AWS Account? If so when uploading the object you should specify `ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'`. Or, you can now [Disable ACLs for your bucket - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html), which will prevent this from happening.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, thanks John. I had to change bucket policy to enforce ownership change (to the bucket owner instead of external account). I have used https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_ownership_controls `BucketOwnerEnforced` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If objects are upload to an Amazon S3 bucket from a different AWS Account, then the 'ownership' of the object will remain with the account that uploaded the object. This can be rather frustrating because the owner of the bucket can't even access the object!

There are two ways to avoid this...

#### Assign ownership

When uploading the object specify an Access Control List (ACL) that assigns ownership to the owner of hte bucket:

```
ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'
```

#### Turn off ACLs

You could [Disable ACLs for your bucket - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html), which avoids the whole problem. In fact, this should probably be the default option for all buckets.